# Enforce VirtualAlloc address less than 32-bits on 64-bit machine

Tags: python, memory, ctypes, kernel32, virtualalloc

I need to allocate a certain space in memory, and I have been using `VirtualAlloc` for this.
However, I have increasingly noticed that `VirtualAlloc` returns an address that exceeds 32 bits, though always less than 33 bits.
The consequence is that when I copy data to this memory address, the computer crashes into a BSOD.

I am using 64-bit windows and a 64-bit Python. I suspect that the program that copies data to the memory is only equipped to handle 32 bits. Is there is a way to enforce `VirtualAlloc` to provide an address within 32 bits?

I am using `Python`, specifically the `ctypes` package to call `VirtualAlloc`, see code below.
Executing this code multiple times changes the address, so repeatedly calling the function below will eventually result in an address below 32 bits. However, I am looking for the cause of and a fail-safe solution to the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import ctypes
mem_commit = 0x1000
page_readwrite = 0x4
size_bytes = 200000  # Allocation sizes are usually around this value

ctypes.windll.kernel32.VirtualAlloc.argtypes = [
    ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_long, ctypes.c_long, ctypes.c_long]
ctypes.windll.kernel32.VirtualAlloc.restype = ctypes.c_int

addr = ctypes.windll.kernel32.VirtualAlloc(
    0, ctypes.c_long(size_bytes), mem_commit, page_readwrite)
```

Note that I free up the memory afterwards using `VirtualFree`.

Comment: I think the crash is due to the truncated value contained in `addr` that you pass to your "memory copying function". See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62036405/how-to-run-shellcode-in-python-3/67403939#67403939).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to enforce a memory allocation with `VirtualAlloc` starting on a 32-bits address memory as long as there is enough free space at this range. Looking in the [msdoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualalloc) we have the following function signature:

```
LPVOID VirtualAlloc(
  LPVOID lpAddress,
  SIZE_T dwSize,
  DWORD  flAllocationType,
  DWORD  flProtect
);
```

And the following description for `lpAddress`:

> The starting address of the region to allocate [...] If this parameter is NULL, the system determines where to allocate the region.

So you can choose the address with this parameter. In your case, you specified 0 for `lpAddress` and it is considered as NULL value.

Furthermore, you must consider that if you choose the memory address you have to ensure that the space is free or `VirtualAlloc` will not give you the space.

Also, you use `mem_commit` without `mem_reserve` and the msdoc says:

> Attempting to commit a specific address range by specifying MEM_COMMIT without MEM_RESERVE and a non-NULL lpAddress fails unless the entire range has already been reserved.

A better option would be to use 0x3000 (MEM_COMMIT|MEM_RESERVE) for `flAllocationType`

Finally, you certainly could use a 64-bits address but you set the result type of `VirtualAlloc` to `c_int` and on Windows, this is an alias for a signed 32 bits `c_long`. So a 64-bits address returned by `VirtualAlloc` would be truncated thus you would use a wrong address to copy your data.